# Maven module not recognizing dependency management in reactor build

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, maven-3

My projects are the following

1. *parent POM project* (has dependency management, packaging POM)
2. *module project 1* (packaging JAR)
3. *module porject 2* (packaging WAR)

In my *parent POM project* the other two projects are defined as modules.

Then I changed some dependencies. After that I wanted to build *parent POM project*, but unfortunately I was getting an error that there are missing dependency versions in *module project 1*.

So I had to uncomment the modules, build *parent POM project* alone, and just then I was able to make my desired Maven reactor build.

The strange thing is that the order of the reactor build seems correct. It's

1. *parent POM project*
2. *module project 1*
3. *module project 2*

Why does it still seem that *module project 1* was wont to build first?

Comment: I assume that the module projects have specified `parent POM` as their <parent/>. Which version of Maven are you using?  Are  you running `mvn verify`? Are you sure all groupIds, artifactIds and versions are correct?

Comment: @RobertScholte Yes, the `parent POM` is specified as their parent. I'm using Maven 3.0.4. `verify` tells me that everything is OK. And the IDs and versions should also be fine.

Comment: So is there still an issue, even after cleaning up your local repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are Module 1 and Module 2 under the ParentDirectory following the Standard Maven DTS?

It seems to be a wrong data tree stucture...